# Math PhD Application with non-math undergrad

Tags: phd

I want to apply a Math PhD program but my undergrad major is engineering.

Currently, I am attending MS math program in UIUC. My GPA is about 3.95 and all coursework (except a upper undergrad course) are graduate level. Expectedly, I will complete 10-15 graduate courses during this MS program.

Does a non-math undergrad harm the Math PhD application? How likely am I admitted to a PhD program in the future?

Answer (score 3):

We can't predict the likelihood of acceptance since it hinges on several factors. Generally speaking though with a MS in math there shouldn't be any issues. In the US there is usually ample opportunity to make up for any missed courses that are required to pass qualifying examinations.

Your later work will be more heavily weighted than the earlier degree, as is typical. My guess is that you are in a pretty good place given the GPA and the institution.